# JQuery. How to load inputs values to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input fields.

```
<input type='text' size='10' name='firstname' id='firstname' />
<input type='text' size='20' name='lastname' id='lastname' />
<input type='password' size='5' name='password' id='password' />
```

I want to get all their values into a single array with jQuery. Like this one.

```
1 => 'Barack',
2 => 'Obama',
3 => '123456'
```

Existing method val() returns value from first match.

```
$('#firstname,#lastname,#password').val(); //returns only first name
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will do:

```
$('#firstname,#lastname,#password').map(function () { 
    return this.value; 
}).get();
```

Comment: There is no need to use the `.val()` method here, `return this.value;` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I made tiniy plugin for that case:

```js
    jQuery.fn.inputs2obj=function (){
        var out={};
        var arr=this.filter(':input').each(function () {
    e=$(this);
        out[e.attr('name')]=e.val();
        }).get();
        return out;
    }
```

Usage example:

```
inputs=$('form').find(':input').inputs2obj();
```