# jQuery/Javascript code to retrieve values of all form elements for AJAX form submission script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, jquery-selectors

I'm building a javascript to submit an html form automatically using jQuery. I'm wondering if it's possible to create a javascript method that will return a map of all form elements and values if given an identifier to find the form with. I'd rather use such a method than manually specifying jQuery selectors for each form element.

```
function form_submit(){
    jQuery.ajax({  
        type: 'post',  
        url: '/signup/',  
        data: map_form_elements_values('my_form'),  
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        //foo
                 }
    });  
    return false; 
}
```

```
<form id="my_form" action="">
<input class="" id="name" type="text" name="last-name" />
<select class="" id="fruit" type="select" name="fruit-name" />
<option>bananas</option>
</select>
</form>
```

the goal would be to have `map_form_elements_values('my_form')` return a map that can be used by the ajax function. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `.serializeArray()` - http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: I hope I correctly understood your problem in my answer, but please let me know if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery forms plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

If you don't need the extra functionality then a simple statement along the lines of:

```
 myData = $("#formToSubmit").serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_form.php",
        data: myData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { ....etc
```

Comment: thanks! That plugin looks very useful I think I'm going to try using it!

Answer (score 1):

I answered on that recently:

[JQuery. How to load inputs values to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859363/jquery-how-to-load-inputs-values-to-an-array/6479710#6479710)

```
jQuery.fn.inputs2obj=function (){
        var out={};
        var arr=this.filter(':input').each(function () {
    e=$(this);
        out[e.attr('name')]=e.val();
        }).get();
        return out;
    }
```

Usage example:

`inputs=$('form').find(:input).inputs2obj();`

Comment: how is this relevant to this question?

Comment: jQuery.ajax({  
         type: 'post',  
         url: '/signup/',  
         data: $('#myform').find(:input).inputs2obj();
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        //foo
                 }
    });  
    return false; 
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize()` or `serializeArray()`

```
var params = $("#my_form").serialize();
        $.post( "/signup/",params,
                 function(data,textStatus, jqXHR){foo ... } )
```

See for example

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/