# Retrieving the value of all the inputs in one array - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery. How to load inputs values to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859363/jquery-how-to-load-inputs-values-to-an-array)

I would like to retrieve the value of all the inputs in one array, so I put

```
var inputs = $('input').val();
    var store = [];
    $(inputs).each(function(){
            $(store).push($(this));
            }
    );
```

But, when I put it in my console and alert the content, I get an undefined message. Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: skip the $() around the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var store = $("input").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: Fine thank you I didn't know about that method !

Comment: @user1611830 And don't forget about `.get()` in order to retrieve pure JS array out of jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

`$('input').val();` returns the value of the first matching element, and not an array.

```
    var store = [];
    $('input').each(function() {
          store.push($(this).val());
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Need changes on different places... Re-Write as

```
var store = [];
$("input").each(function(){
        store.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
var store = $.map($('input'), function(elm) { return elm.value });
```

which will map all the values to an array.